# get value for input in JS file

Tags: javascript

I have a js file with this code:

```html
<form>
   <input onchange="this.value"/>
   <input type="pas" onchange="this.value"/>
</form>
```

This code get data for inputs and replace in main page. Now I don't want replace in html page. I want get input's value and save in string variable. for example:

```html
var name =  ""; // input 1 
var Pas = ""; // input 2
```

How can this work? 
Thank you.

Comment: `variable = this.value;` will save the value in a variable.

Comment: But the variable will be in the parent page, not the current page.

Comment: I have a js file.
Parent should be deleted.
So I do not have access to the values as written.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the input elements id(say, 'name' and 'password') and access it this way

```
var input1 = document.getElementById('name').value;
var input2 = document.getElementById('password').value;
```

Comment: You mean that?parent.document.body.innerHTML = '<form><input id="name" onchange="this.value"/><input id="password" type="password" onchange="this.value"/></form>';
var input1 = document.getElementById('name').value;
var input2 = document.getElementById('password').value;   But did'nt work.